How can restricted randomization to achieve covariate balance lead to imbalance in unobserved variables?
In literature, designing an experiment is considered a trade-off between covariate balance and robustness. For example Harshaw et al. (2024) writes

In an effort to make the estimators more precise, experimenters sometimes restrict the randomization to achieve covariate balance between treatment groups. A concern with this approach is that unobserved characteristics, including potential outcomes, may not be similar between the groups even if the observed characteristics are. [...]
Experimenters must weigh the robustness granted by randomness against possible gains in precision granted by balancing prognostically important covariates.

This implies that methods to reduce covariate imbalance (blocking, matched pair, rerandomization, ...) can accidentally lead to larger differences in unobserved variables then a complete randomized design.
Question:
I don't understand how balancing a covariate could make another unobserved variable non-similar. Can you make a toy example where balancing for one covariate makes unobserved variable non-similar?
My thinking:
If we balance for covariates with restricted randomization, any positively/negatively correlated unobserved variable would also become better balanced. For uncorrelated variables, they would not be better balanced but also not worse than with a completely randomized design.

I don't think the argument is that blocking or other similar methods somehow creates imbalance, but rather that imbalance could exist in spite of your best efforts.  This is, of course, true but not of great consequence as Senn argues here https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23255195/

I agree with @DemetriPananos. The argument is not that restricted randomization induces imbalance, but rather that, by definition, it does not guarantee complete balance. Consider a latent binary characteristic with a low incidence rate that is strongly related to the outcome but only weakly related to the covariates used for restricted randomization. Due to its low incidence, it is possible that, by chance, all positive cases could end up in one treatment arm, resulting in no balance for this latent variable. In practice, the impact on the estimates (not on the "balance") could be minimal.

@DemetriPananos: You got it the wrong way, blocking etc creates balance, not imbalance!

@kjetilbhalvorsen  I don't think I implied that blocking creates imbalance.  Only that the author of the passage OP quotes seems to think that -- despite blocking -- imbalance on unobservables can threaten the validity of the experiment.

@DemetriPananos: ok, might have misread you. But I read the question as WHY balancing on known covariates could create unbalance on unobserved, not if that was a problem! But looking at your ref now!

You say

If we balance for covariates with restricted randomization, any positively/negatively correlated unobserved variable would also become better balanced. For uncorrelated variables, they would not be better balanced but also not worse than with a completely randomized design.

This is a linear intuition! I will denote the observed covariate by $x$ and the unobserved by $z$. If there is a linear correlation between $x$ and $z$, if one is balanced the other will be. But the association between covariates need not be linear. For one example, where we cover $x$ uniformly

but the relation to $z$ is very curved, so the corresponding $z$ sample is very unbalanced. For another example, suppose there is a "triangular correlation" (explained by the plot), also here $x$ is covered uniformly

but $z$ is very unbalanced. Random sampling cannot be a complete solution to this, it will probably make $x$ with less balance, but then $z$ more balanced.
The referenced paper (which I will not repeat here) makes a more mathematical argument. It is in the context of the potential-outcomes model and Horwitz-Thompson estimation, analyzing its mean squared error. It defines robustness as having good precision whatever is the potential outcomes, and shows that a measure of robustness is  minimized by random sampling. Then, using restricted randomization to get better balance, minimizing the measure of robustness in the resulting restricted space, necessarily must give a higher minimum, for the same reason as in Why is sum of squared residuals non-increasing when adding explanatory variable?
They also refer an old debate in statistics, between randomization on the one hand and systematic design on the other. Referring to an old paper by B Efron,
Forcing a sequential experiment to be balanced where the same phenomenon is called accidental bias, randomization then leads to a freedom from accidental bias, while balancing can lead to accidental bias

Thanks @kjetil b halvorsen! I don't understand your definition of balance. For me, covariate balance is the degree to which the distribution of covariates is similar across levels of the treatment. In your figures, the distributions of $z$ are highly skewed, but that does not yet imply that the treatments must be imbalanced with regard to $z$.
Your last paragraph almost answers my questions. Can you make an example where restricted randomization (e.g. within a block defined by covariate) leads to accidental bias?

A few things.
First, my read of the passage is not that restricted randomization leads to imbalance in unobserved covariates.  Rather, despite the researcher's best intentions, restricted randomization does not protect against imbalances in unobserved confounders.
Second, this is true and it is of little consequence.  In his paper Seven myths of randomisation in clinical trials [1], Stephen Senn lists the second myth as "Balance of prognostic factors is necessary for valid inference".  Senn begins this section by discussing a game of dice which he uses as an analogy to randomized experiments.  While I won't go through that here, the relevant material is as follows

It is not necessary for the groups to be balanced. In fact, the probability calculation
applied to a clinical trial automatically makes an allowance for the fact that groups will almost certainly
be unbalanced, and if one knew that they were balanced, then the calculation that is usually performed
would not be correct. (Emphasis Senn)

In short, the statistical calculations we perform are intended to account for possible imbalances between groups. Additionally, any observed imbalance is not a function of the design (were we to perform the experiment again, we might achieve balance or imbalance in the other direction), and so the two groups are balanced in expectation which is the more important point.
In any case, the passage you quote is a non-sequitur. Even though randomization my lead to imbalance on unobservables, the calculations we perform explicitly allow for this and hence do not make imbalance -- actual or otherwise -- a problem.
References

Senn, Stephen. "Seven myths of randomisation in clinical trials." Statistics in medicine 32.9 (2013): 1439-1450.


Thanks @Demetri Pananos! Very helpful. I will challenge your argument in two points

You say that restricted randomization just doesn't protect against imbalanced unobserved covariates (similar as complete randomization). However, according to literature, restricted randomization is worse than complete randomization. This becomes very clear if we look at the equations in chapter 4.1 of Harshaw et al. (2024) where the worst-case mean squared error increases with stronger restriction in the randomization.



You say that statistical calculations we perform, already account for possible imbalance. I agree, small effects (from e.g. unobserved imbalanced covariates) are accounted for in the error term. However, if the effect is large it might mess up the distribution of the error. Observed covariates can be included as a covariate in the model but also there, a severe imbalance will decrease the efficiency of the trial to estimate the treatment effect (variance inflation due to strong correlation between treatment and covariate). So covariate balance is a problem.


After some thought, I have a toy example where rerandomization (to achieve balance in the observed covariate $x$) leads to imbalance in another variable $z$.
Imagine we need to randomize a binary treatment to 20 experimental units with covariate $x$

We want to have similar average value of $x$ across the two treatments. There are ${{20}\choose{10}} = 184\ 756$ different ranomizations possible. We randomly sample 1000 randomizations and choose the one with the lowest covariate imbalance

Notice the large outlier on the right. By choosing a randomization with low covariate imbalance, we will always implicitly 'compensate' for such an outlier by assigning the same treatment to many experimental units at the other end.
This can lead to imbalance in any unobserved covariate $z$, which has a non-linear relationship with $x$ (as similarly pointed out by @kjetil b halvorsen). In the example below, we assume $z = 1/x$ as non-linear relationship.

Instead of assigning the treatments with rerandomization, we could also use another famous restricted randomization scheme: Blocking. Pairs of experimental units with similar $x$ values are created and within each of those blocks one unit is randomized to Control and the other to the Treatment condition.
Below, a potential treatment allocation

This type of restricted randomization might lead to a less perfect balance in $x$ but does not suffer from the same 'outlier compensation' problem as rerandomization.

Can someone can give a toy example where restricted randomization via blocking leads to unobserved covariate imbalance? I would happily accept it as the best solution to the question.
Edit 2024-08-12
Below the code for the last plot (as requested in the comments). I used ggbeeswarm::geom_quasirandom() to avoid overplotting in the dot plots and cowplot::axis_canvas() to add margin plots (similarly as in this post)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(cowplot)
theme_set(theme_bw())

## Log-Normal distribution with outlier
set.seed(18)
x_orig <- rnorm(n = 20)
dat <- tibble(x_orig = x_orig,
              x = exp(x_orig)) %>% 
  mutate(z = 1/x)

## Treatment randomization
set.seed(1)
dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(x_rank = rank(x),
         block = as.factor(ceiling(x_rank/2))) %>% 
  group_by(block) %>% 
  mutate(treatment = sample(c("Control", "Treatment"))) %>% 
  ungroup()

## Treatment group average
agg_dat <- dat %>% 
  group_by(treatment) %>% 
  summarise(x_mean = mean(x),
            z_mean = mean(z))

## Plot
pmain <- dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = z, color = treatment)) +
  geom_function(fun = \(x) 1/x, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_point()
xbox <- axis_canvas(pmain, axis = "x") +
  geom_quasirandom(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = treatment, 
                   color = treatment)) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(x = x_mean, xmin = x_mean, xmax = x_mean, 
                    y = treatment, color = treatment), 
                data = agg_dat) +
  scale_y_discrete()
ybox <- axis_canvas(pmain, axis = "y") +
  geom_quasirandom(data = dat, aes(x = treatment, y = z, 
                                   color = treatment)) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(y = z_mean, ymin = z_mean, ymax = z_mean, 
                    x = treatment, color = treatment), 
                data = agg_dat) +
  scale_x_discrete()
p1 <- insert_xaxis_grob(pmain, xbox, grid::unit(1, "in"), 
                          position = "top")
p2 <- insert_yaxis_grob(p1, ybox, grid::unit(1, "in"), 
                        position = "right")
ggdraw(p2)


Could you share the code for your final plot? I really like the look of it. Also it might improve your answer if you say $z = 1/x$ explicitly (assuming I wasn't mistaken).

@Lukas Lohse Thanks for the comment, I implemented your suggestions.

Thank you very much! I'll add it to my arsenal :)
